# Remove spaces while replacing zero with country code in javascript?

Tags: javascript, html

Basically I'm trying to format numbers entered with zeroes and spaces (04 12347 789) into this = +61412347789. And my brain is just not working at all.

Here's the HTML

```
<input type="text" class="form-control" name="contactNumber" id="contactNumber"/>
<input type="text" class="form-control" name="contactNumberFormatted" id="contactNumberFormatted" readonly />

     <button class="btn btn-primary btn-block" onclick="copyToClipboard()">Copy to clipboard</button>
```

And the script:

```
window.onload = function() {
    var src = document.getElementById("contactNumber"),
        dst = document.getElementById("contactNumberFormatted");
    src.addEventListener('input', function() {
        dst.value = src.value.replace(/0/, '+61');
    });
};

function copyToClipboard() {
    var textBox = document.getElementById("contactNumberFormatted");
    textBox.select();
    document.execCommand("copy");
}
```

I know the below used to remove spaces globally but I don't remember how to add it to the script above.

```
(/\D/g, '')
```

Comment: Sidenote, `/\D/g` matches all non-digit characters, not only spaces. It would remove any letters or symbols as well. Presumably what you want though.

Comment: just asking for information what is '04'?

Comment: @vrugtehagel Thank you, I'm so rusty, it's been a decade lmao

Comment: @NileshChavan It's a mobile number prefix

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You could chain the replace calls:

```
window.onload = function() {
    var src = document.getElementById("contactNumber"),
        dst = document.getElementById("contactNumberFormatted");
    src.addEventListener('input', function() {
        dst.value = src.value.replace(/\D/g, '').replace(/0/, '+61');
    });
};
```

Comment: That worked, you're a star. I need a refresher, I'm stupid af

Comment: Is there a danger someone will enter a number as +614... and that their number has a zero? E.g. that someone enters +614 12340 789  - if so better to use /^0/

Comment: @Frazer Normally they're entered area code + number with spaces. It can be entered as such but if I use /^0/ and enter +614 XXX XXXX the + sign goes away.

Comment: You could append .replace(/^6/, '+6') but maybe @peprumo will have a better solution. I'm no expert either, I just saw a potential problem.

Comment: Try this out: replace(/^0|^61/, '+61') instead of replace(/0/, '+61')